# Sequence of iid $U(0,\theta)$ random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ iid $U(0,\theta)$, $X_{(1)} = \min{\{X_1, \dots, X_n}\}$. Consider the sequence $Y_n = nX_{(1)}$. Does $Y_n$ converge in distribution to some r.v. $Y$?

This is not homework, just a practice problem. The answer in my text (Rohatgi) is $0$ if $y<0$, $1-e^{-y/\theta}$ if $y \geq 0$. My attempt:

Its fairly quick to show if $X_n$ have CDF $F_n$, $X_{(1)}$ has CDF $G$, then $G(y) = 1 - (1- F_1(y))^n$. Thus $Y_n = n(1 - (1 - \frac{y}{\theta})^n)$ for $y \in (0, \theta)$, $0$ for $x<0$, $n$ for $x > \theta$. Taking the limit this doesn't give the desired answer. Anyone know where I'm going wrong? There's clearly a gap in my understanding.

Comment: $Y_n= nG(y)$ as you have it, which makes no sense. Perhaps you wanted to calculate $F_{Y_n}(y)$

Comment: Ah, yes. The answer is clear now thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y>0$
\begin{align}F_{Y_n}(y)&=P(nX_{(1)}\le y)=1-P(nX_{1}>y)=1-P(nX_1>y, nX_2>y, \ldots, nX_n>y)\\&=1-P(nX>y)^n=1-(1-F_X(y/n))^n=1-\left(1-\frac{y}{nθ}\right)^n\to 1-e^{-y/θ}\end{align} as $n \to +\infty$. So, they converge to a r.v. $Y$ with exponential$(1/θ)$ distribution.